# Is there a way to create a character-size based layout with CSS?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have to port a old application who used to run in a system console in text-mode to HTML5.

The layout in HTML5 must mimic the old behavior, that is, the font must be monospaced, the forms, the fields and the text must have dimensions that are a multiple of a character width or height.

So far, I could get an almost satisfying result by using `absolute` positioning, and well chosen values for `font`, `font-size`, `line-height`.

For the height of the elements, I specified my values in `em` so everything falls into place. However, I couldn't find a way to deal easily with elements width.

Let's say I have a label, a text input and a div right below which must have the same exact width. The label is 7 characters long, and so the input should be 7 characters long too.

Something like:

```
mylabel
[input]
[mydiv]
```

However, when using `em` for characters width, I get the following layout:

```
mylabel
[input way too large]
[mydiv way too large]
```

Obviously, since `em` denote the base character height, not its width. So I can't rely on it.

Do you have any solution for this problem ? I'd like to avoid Javascript if possible, but I guess I will have no other option.

I have to target all populars browsers (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera).

Comment: Have you styled the input elements' font to match the plaintext font? Sometimes it is necessary.

Comment: @biziclop: I have. But sadly I must find a solution that would work for all elements, not just `input`s. That is, it could be a `div` instead of the `input` and it should render the same. I updated my question to remove the ambiguity. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: You could try the `ex` unit, which is still vertical, but it is more close to character width. Or if nothing helps, you can use the `size="chars"` attribute: `<input type="text" value="0123456789" size="10">`  example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Fbwx/ Unfortunately this also fails.

Comment: Maybe torturing `letter-spacing` can also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I have no idea of whether this is supported by any browsers yet, but someday this may be an acceptable solution.</sub>

The [CSS3 Values and Units Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) defines the [`ch` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch-unit)

> Equal to the advance measure of the `"0"` (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it.

"advance measure" is essentially the width of the character. In a monospaced typeface, all the character widths are identical.

The alternative is to figure out what the width of a character is for each font-size being used, and use multiples of that value when defining widths. If you're lucky it'll be a fraction of an `em` unit.

Comment: The `ch` unit was not supported on my target browsers (I wish it were) so I had to measure manually the character width in avascript, and compute the elements dimensions from there. Accepting this answer, as I believe it will become more and more true in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`ex` is a unit similar to `em` but the height of a lower case `x`, not a capital `M`. In monospace fonts, you will often find the `x` is practically square making `ex` approximately equal to the width of a character.

CSS Units: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Sorry, only just saw the comment from biziclop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there is a small difference in rendering for very long lines as its only an approximation of the width.

Comment: You may be able to find a monospace font where the height of x equals the width. For example Consolas is a lot closer than Courier.

Comment: obligatory [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) reference. Instead of linking to a bad resource, how about using [w3.org's documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ex-unit).